# Sharepoint 2013: List View - boxed one column

Tags: custom-list, item-styles

Sharepoint 2013: I have created a form; with a custom list and have chosen the boxed style and I need to display the contents in a single column.

Can anyone advise how I can achieve this please

Comment: Could you explain more what you are trying to do? How many columns in your form? What type of columns?

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding.  The form is composed of 8 x fields, I have created a new view and then changed the style option to 'boxed'. This has produced two columns. The next stage is for the output to presented to staff and this needs to be in a single column view. The layout needs to be vertical (rather than horizontal).

Comment: Are the 8 fields single text or are there different fields? Boxed with labels or boxed style only?

Comment: they are Boxed with labels and seperate fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a script editor web part to the page where your list is and add some CSS to make it one box per row/item.

```
<style type="text/css">
table.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td {
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-width: 1px 0px;
float: right;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

If you wanna hide the horizontal column names, add this CSS inside the style tags.

```
.ms-viewheadertr {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user19952 that worked a treat. Anyone needing this in the future and you wonder why everything has disappeared from your page - go back into the script editor and make sure you have the code as follows and it will work:

'code'<style type="text/css">
table.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td {
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-width: 1px 0px;
float: right;
width: 100%;
}
</style>'code'

**You need the "speech mark" after "text/css"**

Comment: My Apologies, i corrected the missing character.